# Comparing Post array with Json array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am working on on a college project in which i am making Online MCQ test for exams . I have created a json file stroing the data of question. I print the question in my php file with foreach loop. I am stuck at a place where i have a POST array of selected radio button and on another page an array of correct answer in JSON file. I want to compare both arrays to count number of correct and wring answer. The only bug my code have is what is someone have not choosed any option in question. Then my POST array wouldnt be compared perfectly. and second is 
Post array is in format

```
Array ( [question1] => op3 [question2] => op2 [question3] => op3 [question4] => op1 [question5] => op3 [submit] => SUBMIT )
```

And JSON array is like this

```
 [0] => op1 [1] => op1 [2] => op1 [3] => op1 [4] => op1 )
```

How would i compare these two diffrently indexed array so that i can count the numbers of wrong and right..

This is my total code 
HTML

```
form id="gi" method="post" action="checkAnswer.php">

      <?php
      foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) {
          echo
          "<p><span class='que'> Question</span>&nbsp;&nbsp". $value['number']."&nbsp;&nbsp". "<br><hr class='line'>". $value['question']."<br><br>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio'  name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1'>" ." " , $value['op1']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op2'>" ." " , $value['op2']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op3'>"." "  , $value['op3']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op4'>"." " , $value['op4']."</pre>".
          "</p>";
      }
      ?>
      <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
      <!-- <button onclick="handleClick()">click</button> -->
       </form>
```

This is json

```
[

      {
          "number": 1,
          "question": "Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "op1" : 20,
          "op2" : 30,
          "op3" : 59,
          "op4" : 54,
          "correct_answer": "op1"
      },
      {
          "number": 2,
          "question": "Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "op1" : 20,
          "op2" : 30,
          "op3" : 59,
          "op4" : 54,
          "correct_answer": "op1"
      },
      {
          "number": 3,
          "question": "Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "op1" : 20,
          "op2" : 30,
          "op3" : 59,
          "op4" : 54,
          "correct_answer": "op1"
      }
]
```

This is code where i am operforming the common operations

````
<?php
$contentOfJsonFile = file_get_contents("example_10.json");
$JsonData = json_decode($contentOfJsonFile, true);

$correctAnswerArray = [];



// Defination of all global variables 
$wrongCount = 1;


// this will push the correct answer from the json to an array

foreach ($JsonData as $key => $value) {
    array_push($correctAnswerArray, $value['correct_answer']);
}

print_r($correctAnswerArray);

// this is printing the post array

$userAnswerArray = $_POST;
print_r($userAnswerArray);



//comparing two arrays 
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($userAnswerArray); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($correctAnswerArray); $j++) {
        if ($correctAnswerArray[$j] != $userAnswerArray[$i])
            $wrongCount++;
        else
            $correctCount++;
    }
}

echo $correctCount;
echo $wrongCount;
?>```
````

Answer (score 0):

```php
foreach ($userAwnserArray as $key => $answer) {
    # get question number
    $questionNumber = substr($key, -1);
    # get answer of the question in the foreach loop and compare to the correct answer
    if ($correctAnswerArray[$questionNumber] === $answer) {
        # increment correct
        $correctCount++;
    } else {
        # increment wrong
        $wrongCount++;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it but I think it will push you in the right direction

Comment: I will surely try this. Can you help with what if a user left any question without solving . Don't you think the POST  array will get disturb . How would i send a 0 for a question if left by user. Have any idea ?

Comment: Add a `required` tag to all required questions, if you have 4 radio inputs with the same name add the required tag to at least one and it should verify the user selected at least one radio input